# Crear índices en python

Tags: python

He creado un dataframe con varios archivos json de un mismo directorio, y quiero crear un índice para extraer una columna, eliminar Nas y volver a unir con Merge.

El problema es que al ser archivos diferentes, el dataframe resultante con todos los archivos json (los uní con concat) comienza de 0 cada vez que ha cargado uno de los archivos y al crear un índice hace lo mismo.

He probado con set_index,  creando una Serie con el número de filas total del dataframe para crear una columna id y hace lo mismo, empieza en 0 cada archivo (Son 10 archivos json).

¿Cómo podría crear un id único sin que empiece de 0 cada archivo?

Gracias por la atención

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta, añade el código con lo que tienes y has intentado y añade también un ejemplo con lo que tienes y el resultado que esperas. Así nos será más fácil para las personas que te queremos ayudar.